# AVAssetExportSession exports with wrong export time

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-audio, avassetexportsession

I'd like to trim and export my .caf file
My code is:

```
CMTime startTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(self.audioFile.totalDuration * self.startSelectionPositionValue, NSEC_PER_SEC);
    CMTime endTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(self.audioFile.totalDuration * self.endSelectionPositionValue, NSEC_PER_SEC);
    float startTimeInSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(startTime);
    float endTimeInSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(endTime);
    CMTimeRange exportTimeRange = CMTimeRangeFromTimeToTime(startTime, endTime);
    float duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(exportTimeRange.duration);
```

For example. I'd like to trim from 0 to 15 seconds.
`startTimeInSeconds` prints 0. `endTimeInSeconds` prints 15. `exportTimeRange.duration` prints 15. But in result my file length is 15.07. 
Exporter code:

```
    AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [AVAssetExportSession exportSessionWithAsset:sampleAsset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A];
        exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A;
        exporter.outputURL = exportUrl;
        exporter.timeRange = exportTimeRange;
        exporter.audioMix = audioMix;
[exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^(void) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:NO];
            switch (exporter.status) {
                case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted: {
                    // My completion code is there
                    break;
                }
                default:
                    break;
            }
        });
    }];
```

Thanks in advance :)